# How to handle an exception while converting a literal present in a list to float?

Tags: python, list, floating-point, type-conversion, strip

```
A=[None, '0.50', '2', '4', '6', '0', '0', '0', '0.00', '0', '0', '0', '5', '1', '5', '5', '1', '1', '0', '1', '2', '2', '2', '0 (1:1)', '0', '0', '2', '2', '0', '0', '1', '2', '0']
B=[]
for elem in A:
    if elem is not None:
        B.append(float(elem.strip("''")))
    else:
         B.append(elem )
print B
```

I have a list which has values shown above. When I am trying to add to an excel sheet using pandas, it is being added as text rather than float or int. I want to remove quotation marks so that it won't be seen as text in excel sheet, I know it can be done using split, and if I try to convert all of these to float, it throws an exception for this '0(1:1)' element saying that invalid literal for for float.How do I handle this?

Comment: Do you care about the item `0 (1:1)`?

Comment: Well what do you want to do with `'0 (1:1)'`?

Comment: You mention pandas - have you looked at [pandas.to_numeric](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) and specifying errors='coerce' ?

Comment: so I am trying to parse an xml file using element tree and I am trying to append all the values to a list. That xml file has these values.So I can't avoid those values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpler solution is to wrap the `for` body in a `try-except` and append `None` or the original value (`elem`) if it fails for a particular iteration:

```
A = [None, '0.50', '2', '4', '6', '0', '0', '0', '0.00', '0', '0', '0', '5', '1', '5', '5', '1', '1', '0', '1', '2', '2', '2', '0 (1:1)', '0', '0', '2', '2', '0', '0', '1', '2', '0']

B = []

for elem in A:
    try:
        B.append(float(elem))
    except (ValueError, TypeError) as error:
        B.append(elem)

        # Or, if you don't want to preserve the non-numeric values:

        # B.append(None)

print(B)
```

A `ValueError` will be thrown when `elem` can't be parsed as `float`, while `TypeError` will be thrown when `elem` is `None`.

Like that you don't need to check if `elem` is `None` using and `if` and both exceptions can be handled consistently (assuming that's what you want).

Note the `.strip("''")` is not needed as it is actually not doing anything. [According to the docs, strip() will...](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip):

> Return a copy of the string with the leading and trailing characters removed.

That is, it will try to remove `''` from the start and the end of your values, but none of your values start or end with two single quotes. Actually, any of them contain quotes at all, those around them are just the way to represent a string, but are not part of their value.

Also, [`float()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) will automatically take care of converting a string representation of a number (`'1'`) to `Float`.

Comment: I want to retain 0(1:1) in the list and I don't want them to be none.

Comment: @user1681102 Then use the commented out code in the `except` block: `B.append(elem)`

Comment: Yes, only those values that are actually numeric will be converted to `float`. The rest will be left untouched.

Comment: I can't upvote this as long as it has a [bare except](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/doanddont.html#except): "using a bare `except:` is almost never a good idea": `except (TypeError, ValueError):` is much, much better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `literal_eval` from `ast` module and use a `try ... except` block like this example:

```
from ast import literal_eval

A=[None, '0.50', '2', '4', '6', '0', '0', '0', '0.00', '0', '0', '0', '5', '1', '5', '5', '1', '1', '0', '1', '2', '2', '2', '0 (1:1)', '0', '0', '2', '2', '0', '0', '1', '2', '0']

def evaluate(a):
    for k in a:
        try:
            # Or if you want: use yield float(k)
            yield literal_eval(k)
        except ValueError:
            yield k
        except SyntaxError:
            yield k

>>> list(evaluate(A))
[None, 0.5, 2, 4, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0.0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, '0(1:1)', 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0]
```

Comment: I get TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: Did you run the same example i gave in my answer ? or you've a different input ? because this example runs well without any errors.

Comment: Well this example should run without any erros and give the same output i gave within Python3

Comment: I am using python2.7.10

Comment: I just test again the code within `Python 2.7.12` and it works like a charm.